# Instantiate new views from storyboard scene dock items

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

I have attached UIViews to a storyboard scene dock and connected them to an IBOutlet. For mosts views this is an one-to-one relationship, but sometimes I'd like to use the view as a template and create new instances as if it was a nib.

Is this possible to to from views put in the scene dock?

Comment: Any success with this one ?

Comment: No, I ended up using creating container views in code and adding a separate storyboard scene instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create subclass of the UIView and set the class in the interface builder to that particular class.

You can create subclass of the UIView, set placeholder view in the storyboard and add your particular, nib view to that placeholder.

It is on you to decide which approach you want.